# Schedule task regularly at alternating times in python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, schedule

I would like to schedule a task at minute :57 and minute :05, alternating every two hours. So the intervall during execution is alternating between 52 minutes and 68 minutes, on average 60 minutes.
For a given hour x the times when I would like to execute code are:
x:05; x:57; (x+2):05, (x+2):57; ...
I currently use the python module schedule and the following code:

```
schedule.every(2).hours.at(':05').do(job1)
schedule.every(2).hours.at(':57').do(job2)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

How can I best ensure that the code is not running at x:57 and then again at (x+1):05 the following hour (meaning the intervall is only 8 minutes long)?

Edit: I could add something along the lines of:

```
minutes = datetime.now().minutes
if not (minutes  < 5 or minutes  > 57):
    time.sleep(60 - minutes)
```

and then schedule but I would miss 2 executions which is not ideal.

Comment: So if you start this at 1:00 you want the job to run at 1:05, 2:05, 2:57, 3:57, 4:05?

Comment: If I start it at 1:00 I would like to run it at 1:05, 1:57, 3:05, 3:57... If I actually start it at 1:00 my code above should work just fine. But it should work flawlessly for any time. If I start it let's say at 1:50 it should first execute at 1:57 and next 3:05 not 2:05. Hope that clear things up!

Comment: So if you start it at 2:00 you want the first run to be at 3:05 or 2:05?

Comment: First one at 2:05